# Как переключать табы bootstrap собственной независимой кнопкой?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Есть секция табов на `bootstrap` [из примера](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/). Работают, переключаются, все ок, но у меня вопрос: как переключить теперь любой из табов своей независимой кнопкой?

```
<a class="btn bt-info" id="btn-bottom" data-toggle="tab">Show Third</a>
```

[Тренеруюсь в фидле](http://jsfiddle.net/f26zsvby/7/)

```js
if ($('#btn-bottom').length) {
  $('#btn-bottom[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    e.target // newly activated tab
    e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">First</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Second</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Third</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Forth</div>
  </div>

  <a class="btn bt-info" id="btn-bottom" data-toggle="tab">Show Third</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489958/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите кнопкой на конкретный таб тогда так:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(){
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#messages"]').tab('show');
    });

});
</script>
```